# How to set the displayed start and end date in the Codename One date picker?

Tags: codenameone

I would like to display a date picker in my app, but I need to set the the limits on the earliest and latest shown dates. How can I do it with Codename One `PickerComponent`?  Or are there any other better ways to do it?

[image: This is the example of what I have right now]

Comment: Why not update `setEndDate()` of the first picker to match the date of the second picker?

Comment: @ShaiAlmog Thank you. I tried it before, but it didn't work. I just realized that in order it to be working the picker must also include `setStartDate()` . 
Now it works!

Comment: Just to clarify, I have one picker. I just wanted to set the range of displayed dates (years in my case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found - my `PickerComponent` must include both `setStartDate()` and `setEndDate()`.
Example --
[image]